# How to return a value based on a variable property

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a program that will return true if a menu item is vegetarian but looking to see if any of the ingredients are in the "meat" category that is all predefined. I've tried reordering the ingredients but that doesn't work either.
The ingredients are defined as follows

```
const egg = createNewIngredient('egg', 'protein')
const tomato = createNewIngredient('tomato', 'fruit')
const spinach = createNewIngredient('spinach', 'vegetable')
const mushroom = createNewIngredient('mushroom', 'vegetable')
const feta = createNewIngredient('feta', 'cheese')
const cheddar = createNewIngredient('cheddar', 'cheese')
const bacon = createNewIngredient('bacon', 'meat')
```

And this is the line that's calling the function;

```
const baconCheeseOmelette = createNewMeal('Bacon and Cheese Omelette', [
  cheddar,
  egg,
  bacon
])
```

```
const createNewMeal = (name, ingredients) => {
    return {
        name,
        ingredients,
        isVegetarian() {
            if (ingredients.category === "meat") {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        },
        isDelicious() {
            if (ingredients.category === "cheese") {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        },
    }
}
export default createNewMeal
```

This is the function that is supposed to look into the category of the ingredients.

Comment: `if (this.ingredients.some(ingredient => ingredient.category === "meat")) {`

Comment: @skara9 That would make it NOT vegetarian

Comment: @mplungjan yes, it's to plug into OP's code `if () return false`

Comment: @skara9 Ah, yeah, sorry I had my own code in mind when I read yours

Answer (score 1):

You are not looking through all ingredients.

Also no need to use ifs to set a value to true or false from a true or false statement

```js
const createNewIngredient = (name,category) => ({name,category});
const egg = createNewIngredient('egg', 'protein')
const tomato = createNewIngredient('tomato', 'fruit')
const spinach = createNewIngredient('spinach', 'vegetable')
const mushroom = createNewIngredient('mushroom', 'vegetable')
const feta = createNewIngredient('feta', 'cheese')
const cheddar = createNewIngredient('cheddar', 'cheese')
const bacon = createNewIngredient('bacon', 'meat')

const createNewMeal = (name, ingredients) => {
  return {
    name,
    ingredients,
    isVegetarian: () => !ingredients.some(({category}) => category === "meat"),
    isDelicious:  () => ingredients.some(({category}) => category === "cheese")
  }
}

const baconCheeseOmelette = createNewMeal('Bacon and Cheese Omelette', [
  cheddar,
  egg,
  bacon
])

console.log(baconCheeseOmelette.isVegetarian())
console.log(baconCheeseOmelette.isDelicious())
```

Comment: Worth noting this won't account for any changes to the `ingredients` property.

Comment: @skara9 What do you mean? You mean after the recipe has been created?

Comment: Yes, the methods will be locked to the `ingredients` argument passed in on construction rather than the object's property.

Comment: Is that not how it is supposed to be?

Comment: Depends on OP's intent. Just worth noting.